# Type name choosing :: An Interface name for functions returning a value

Tags: java, function, variables, variable-names

It's always hard to choose better variable/Type names. I am stuck choosing a name for an interface

I want to classify functions based on whether they return values or not. Here are some choices I made and why I rejected them.

```
ReturningFunction  : a function which doesn't return is hung. I don't want to confuse
OutputtingFunction : a function which outputs to stdout can return void so we can't call it with this name
VoidFunction       : a function which is void?
```

I tried googling but no luck. Please suggest some names :)

Comment: Whether a function prints to stdout has nothing to do with its return type.

Comment: @khelwood That's why I didn't choose that name :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to reuse the interfaces provided by Java or, if they're not sufficient, follow their naming convention in the [java.util.function package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html):

Similar to `VoidFunction`:

> `Consumer<T>` Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and returns no result.
>
> `BiConsumer<T,​U>` Represents an operation that accepts two input arguments and returns no result.

Similar to `ReturningFunction`:

> `Function<T,​R>` Represents a function that accepts one argument and produces a result.
>
> `BiFunction<T,​U,​R>` Represents a function that accepts two arguments and produces a result.
>
> `Supplier<T>` Represents a supplier of results.

For "outputs to stdout", you probably don't want an interface at all.  Instead, you'd want a concrete class like the following:

```
final class SystemOutConsumer<A> implements Consumer<A> {

    private final BiConsumer<PrintStream, A> printStreamABiConsumer;

    public SystemOutConsumer(
            final BiConsumer<PrintStream, A> printStreamABiConsumer) {

        this.printStreamABiConsumer = printStreamABiConsumer;
    }

    public void accept(final A a) {

        printStreamABiConsumer.accept(System.out, a);
    }
}
```